# How to align six ImageView with custom shape to complete a full circle

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview, android-drawable

I have 6 `ImageView` that are aligned together in full circle, which means each ImagView must have a degree of `60`, but I couldn't get this exact shape using drawable XML and even if I could, how could I align them to together in to complete a circle? *(see the picture below)*

[image]

PS: I'm using this [library](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) to mask the shape with the ImageView

Comment: Are these masked pictures or just solid colors? Do they have text on them? Are they independently clickable?

Comment: not necessarily, the colors are just an example, and no text just an ImageView with that specific shape, and yes each image has its own click action.